# Pass a function as a parameter with templates in C++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, containers

The function i am writing below is made to time how long it takes to process a function.

```
// return type for func(pointer to func)(parameters for func), container eg.vector
clock_t timeFuction(double(*f)(vector<double>), vector<double> v)
{
    auto start = clock();
    f(v);
    return clock() - start;
}
```

This is the function i want to test in my timeFunction.

```
template<typename T>
double standardDeviation(T v)
{
    auto tempMean = mean(v); //declared else where
    double sq_sum = inner_product(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), 0.0);
    double stdev = sqrt(sq_sum / v.size() - tempMean * tempMean);
    return stdev;
}
```

standardDiviation was made with a template so it can accept any c++ container and i want to do the same with timeFunction, so i tried the following.

```
template<typename T>
clock_t timeFuction(double(*f)(T), T v)
{
    auto start = clock();
    f(v);
    return clock() - start;
}
```

but this gives me errors like cannot use function template "double standardDiviation(T)" and could not deduce template argument for "overloaded function"

This is how i called the function in main.

```
int main()
{
    static vector<double> v;
    for( double i=0; i<100000; ++i )
        v.push_back( i );

    cout << standardDeviation(v) << endl; // this works fine
    cout << timeFuction(standardDeviation,v) << endl; //this does not work

}
```

how do i fix the timeFunction so it works with any c++ container. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to pass a pointer-to-a-function-template. But no such thing exists.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Seems to work fine for me on g++ 4.6.3

Comment: works fine for me too g++ 4.6.3

Comment: Passing large objects by value is not a good idea because it will require a lot of copying, pass it by const reference instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to compile this code on GCC 4.7.1. It compiles and works fine. What compiler are you using? If it is not able to deduce template argument then try to specify it explicitly, i.e. use:

```
cout << timeFuction(standardDeviation< vector<double> >,v) << endl;
```

Also, when asking questions you should try to remove all unnecessary code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
double standardDeviation(T v)
{
    return 5;
}

template<typename T>
int timeFuction(double(*f)(T), T v)
{
   // auto start = clock();
    f(v);
    return 0;//clock() - start;
}

int main()
{
    static vector<double> v;
    for( double i=0; i<100000; ++i )
        v.push_back( i );

    cout << standardDeviation(v) << endl; // this works fine
    cout << timeFuction(standardDeviation,v) << endl; // this also work

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I am currently downloading Visual Studio 2010 and i will try to compile the code using that.

Comment: It compiles fine for me on MinGW-g++-4.6.2 too

Comment: i specified the template argument and it works. Thank you so much.